# How to filter to get one unique record using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table similar to this. If there is a confirmed record, I want to select the oldest record and if not, select the most recent one. In this case, I would want the 4_A record.

| ID | Record | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1_A | 1 | auto | 4/7/2021 |
| 2_A | 1 | confirmed | 4/1/2021 |
| 3_A | 1 | suggested | 4/5/2021 |
| 4_A | 1 | confirmed | 4/2/2021 |
| 5_A | 1 | suggested | 4/5/2021 |

I've been able to use the a window function and QUALIFY to filter the most recent one but not sure how to include the TYPE field into the mix.

```
SELECT * from TABLE  WHERE QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD ORDER BY RECORD,DATE DESC) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you mean the oldest confirmed date if there is a confrimed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD 
                                 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Type = 'Confirmed' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
                                          (CASE WHEN Type = 'Confirmed' THEN DATE END) ASC,
                                          DATE ASC
                                 ) = 1;
```

If you really mean the oldest date if there is a confirmed, then:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
QUALIFY (CASE WHEN COUNT_IF( Type = 'Confirmed') OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD) 
              THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD ORDER BY DATE)
              THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RECORD ORDER BY DATE DESC)
         END) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon!! I did mean the oldest confirmed date if it is available.